# Tabuada interativa - Deseja continuar? (S/N)

Tags: loop, while

Em um dos exercícios do curso que estou fazendo, adaptei o código de uma tabuada interativa onde, depois do usuário digitar um número para a tabuada e o programa executar, é oferecida a opção "Deseja continuar? (S/N)". Segue o código abaixo:

---

```
num = int(input('Digite o numero para a tabuada'))
for mult in range(1,11):
    print(f'{num} x {mult} = {num*mult}')  

cont = str(input('Deseja ver a tabuada de outro número? (S/N) \n')).strip().lower()
s = 's' in cont
n = 'n' in cont

if s == True:
    num = int(input('Digite o numero para a tabuada'))
    print()
    for mult in range(1,11):
        print(f'{num} x {mult} = {num*mult}')

elif n == True:
    print()
    print('Um abraço e até logo! :)')
```

---

O problema que tive foi de não conseguir deixar ele dinâmico como, por exemplo, executar a opção "sim" até que o usuário digite a opção "não" e encerre o programa.

O que consegui escrever foi um looping correto de apenas duas vezes, mas a ideia seria encaixar um while para não deixar o código com muitas linhas.

Pergunta: Como faço para deixar a repetição ativa até que o usuário digite, por exemplo, 10 vezes a opção "sim" até que ele decida encerrar e, ao mesmo tempo, fazer isso com o menor número de linhas no código?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, vou deixar apenas a tua referência. Eu tinha aprendido que era má prática usar o `while true`. Boa sacada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de conseguir o resultado desejado é colocando o código que deseja dentro de um loop. E enquanto o usuário continuar respondendo que deseja continuar, manter o loop em execução.

Uma implementação possível seria declarar um bloco de repetição while true, executar o seu código e após a execução perguntar se deseja executar novamente,  caso o usuário responder que não, colocar uma condição de parada (condição de saída) para que o programa pare a execução. Finalizando a execução do código.

Veja o exemplo:

```
while True: #<-- bloco de repetição while true
    
    # seu código

    cont = str(input('Deseja continuar? (S/N)')).strip().lower() #<-- pergunta
    if cont == 'n': #<-- condição de parada
        break
 
print('Um abraço e até logo! :)')
```

Essa solução respeita o princípio [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/103217).

---

Se deseja uma solução que possui um pouco de redundância então pode executar pelo menos uma vez e após a primeira execução a gente mantém o usuário em um loop.

Da seguinte forma:

```
# seu código

cont = input('Deseja ver a tabuada de outro número? (S/N)') #pergunta
while not cont.lower() == 'n':
     
     # seu código

     cont = input('Deseja continuar? (S/N)')

print('Um abraço e até logo! :)')
```

Repare que na implementação acima, a regra do while está invertida em relação à regra do if (quando comparado com a primeira implementação). Que é evidenciado pela palavra chave `not`.
Para a implementação em Python, respeite sempre as indentações de escopo do código, pois em Python os espaços são significativos.

Comment: Só uma correção, o DRY não é uma boa ou má pratica, o Dry é um principio de programação ou seja, um proposição fundamental que serve de base para o cadeia de raciocínio de desenvolvimento de Software.. Classificar conceitos de  desenvolvimento com boas ou más práticas em geral é uma incoerência não evidenciada pois ao assumir que algo é uma boa prática você está assumindo que esse algo é válido para todos os casos. Quando ler ou ouvir que uma maneira específica de fazer as coisas é uma boa prática, pergunte-se quais os critérios e fontes de concessão do status de melhor prática?

Comment: `if 'n' in cont` não é uma boa forma de verificar, porque se vc digitar qualquer coisa que tenha um "n" no meio, vai entrar nesse `if` - digite, por exemplo, "banana" ou "123n456". Isso porque `a in b` verifica se a string `a` é uma substring de `b`. Neste caso, o melhor seria ver se é igual: `if cont == 'n'`. Quanto a essa história de "boa prática", reforço o que o @AugustoVasques disse. Infelizmente "boa prática" virou sinônimo de fanatismo religioso, que as pessoas seguem cegamente sem pensar. O melhor é entender o mecanismo, os prós e contras, e então analisar se faz sentido em cada caso.

Comment: @hkotsubo, deixei consistente nas duas implementações.

Comment: A resposta foi de @Danizavtz ou @augustovasquez? Estou me acostumando aqui com o SO.

Comment: eu copiei a do @augustovasquez a versão DRY da resposta, depois eu deixei uma outra maneira de resolver o problema, que não usa o DRY. Mais parecida com a sua pergunta original.

Comment: @hkotsubo no caso que você mencionou da letra "n", não ficaria intuitivo a pessoa digitar "sim", "não", "nao", "s",  S", "n" ou "N" e as funções built-in ".strip()" e ".lower()" não seriam suficientes para resolver esse problema? Pergunta honesta de iniciante mesmo. Abraços

Comment: Ok, entendido @Danizavtz

Comment: @Luix78 Neste caso poderia ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/89sYiZ - Desta forma fica bem flexível, se quiser mais opções, basta adicionar em `opcoes_sim` e `opcoes_nao`. E complementando, `input` já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input(...))` é redundante e desnecessário, não precisa de `str` neste caso.

Comment: Excelente @hkotsubo